# What does "could be made that without it" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I have been trying to translate an article about [wearable smart watches](http://www.phonearena.com/news/To-wearable-or-not-to-wearable_id64018). But there is a sentence which is unclear to me. I don't know what does "could be made that without it" mean in the following context?

> I know I can’t be the only one that finds nightly recharging an
>   irritation. I know we do the same thing with our smartphones, but that
>   is a whole different appliance. My smartphone is my nerve center of
>   mobile communications. The argument **could be made that without it**, any
>   high-tech wearable is useless in carrying out its task, so in exchange
>   for pretty much managing my entire digital identity (more on that
>   later), I am willing to keep the battery juiced.

P.S: In the above context, author is reviewing wearable smart watches and a bit comparing it to smartphones.

Comment: [The argument] [could be made] [that] [ without it (smartphone), any high-tech wearable is useless in carrying out its task].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sentence is confusing because it uses *heavy noun phrase shift*. This just means that part of the subject has moved to the end of the clause. Here is the original clause. I have put the subject of the clause in **bold**:

- **The argument** could be made **that without it, any high-tech wearable is useless in carrying out its task**.

In this clause the word it, means "my smartphone".

Here is a version without heavy noun phrase shift:

- **The argument that [without it, any high-tech wearable is useless in carrying out its task]** could be made.

This sentence is passive and so a bit difficult to understand. Let's make it active so that we can understand it better:

- I could make the argument that [without it, any high-tech wearable is useless in carrying out its task].

This sentence is still complicated because the preposition phrase *without it* is at the beginning of the argument instead of the end. Also, "*in carrying out its task*" doesn't really give us any extra information. "*Useless in carrying out its task*" just means "*useless*"! Let's move "*without it*" to the end of the clause, and let's leave out "*in carrying out its task*"

- I could make the argument that any high-tech wearable is useless without it.

Remember that "*it*" here means "*my smartphone*". So the clause means:

- I could make the argument that any high-tech wearable is useless without my smartphone.

Hope this is helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be parsing the sentence in a confusing way.

> The argument could be made that without it, any high-tech wearable is useless in carrying out its task.

Here, *it* refers to your smartphone (from the previous sentence).

The statement is:

> Without you smartphone, any high-tech wearable is useless in carrying out its task.

And the author just says that this statement can be used as an argument:

> The following argument could be made: *without you smartphone, any high-tech wearable is useless in carrying out its task*.